# Alternatives to binomial test when the observations are not independent

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, binomial-distribution

In my experiment, participants had to choose between two possible answers (say A and B) for different (40+) questions. I want to test whether option A is chosen more frequently than the alternative; I would have used a binomial test against P = 0.5, but the data do not meet the assumptions of a binomial test, in that the samples are not mutually independent.

In my data, it would not be fair to assume that the samples are mutually independent, since (a) some clusters of responses are given by the same participant, and (b) some clusters of responses correspond to the same question, answered to by different participants.

One way to account for non-independence in the data is through mixed effects models; in this case I'd have to use a generalized binomial mixed effects models without the predictor (i.e. intercept only). I wanted to ask you whether you had in mind some other alternatives that would be adequate for this kind of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your situation is similar to that of [item-response-theory](/questions/tagged/item-response-theory), so look into that. Otherwise your suggestion seems the right one, use a random intercept per subject, and another random intercept per question.